# Is there a way to hide the fact that you minimize the browser or unfocus from some window

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

So I was wondering if there is a way to hide you're activity from a webpage that uses JavaScript (And libraries such as AjaX or JQuery).
By activity I mean that I don't what the webpage to know that I'm switching tabs or minimizing the browser, unfocusing and etc.

I know you can track someones activity like so:

```
$(window).focus(function() {
    console.log("YOU'RE BACK")
});

$(window).blur(function() {
    console.log("YOU'RE OUT")
});
```

And I can stop it by writing the following in the console:

```
$(window).off()
```

But I'm sure there are million other ways to do so, and I want to make sure that any specific webpage doesn't do so.

So, How can I make sure that no sensitive information leaked?

also note that I don't want to block JavaScript completely, because I want the webpage to still work.

Comment: What do you mean by no sensitive information leaked?

Comment: Short answer is ... probably not solvable for all pages you visit unless there is some sort of browser extension to do it

Comment: @charlietfl I know, that's what I'm aiming for though...

Comment: @Keith I gave some examples, reread my question, mainly the fact that u switched tabs

Comment: I'm still lost, how is switching tabs leaking sensitive information?  What about mouse movement, keyboard input.  Iow: if I wanted to know you had left the site, I could maybe track these too.

Comment: @Keith You're correct but let's start with how to prevent someone from knowing that you switched tabs or resized you're browser or just minimized it and went to use other apps like spotify or whatsapp XD

Comment: So you want a browser extension that convinces a website that it's in use when it actually isn't?  (The reverse won't serve your purpose, because some websites deliberately stop working when they think they're not in use.)  Consider that such a browser extension would be very bad for your computer's performance.

Comment: @Brilliand Yeah, pretty much.

Comment: @Brilliand I can run a VM and run my website in it and then de-attach from the VM into my main OS, but I think it's an overkill and I'm looking for an in-browser solution if you may...

Comment: ...and the website might still be able to tell that it's not in use, by measuring mouse movements like Google's checkbox captcha does.

Comment: @Brilliand But it's far less obvious, given the assumption that you will come back to it in a few moments. (Yes that's a new assumption I know)

Comment: I doubt that any such thing exists, but I'll leave it for someone else to say for sure.

Comment: Focus and blur are not made to track if a browser is minimized or not. This is what Page Visibility API is used for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API